# Laravel 5.2 Queuing events

Tags: php, queue, laravel-5

I have some events that perform CRUD, uploads, and emails. I would like to queue these events. I did some research and found that all I need to do is configure my queue driver and implement ShouldQueue contract in my event listeners. Since I'm using redis as my Cache and session driver, I went ahead and used redis as my queue driver. When I fire my events without using ShouldQueue, everything works fine, I get emails, data gets added to DB ..etc. But when I add ShouldQueue to my event listeners and I run queue:listen I fire my events but nothing gets added or executed in the queue. I also don't get any emails, DB ...etc. What am I missing? Here is an example of my code:

.env file

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
```

App\Events\ContactUs\CustomerContactUs

```
use SerializesModels;
/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 */
public function __construct()
{

}
```

App\Listeners\ContactedUs\SendCustomerEmailToUs

```
private $mailer;
private $request;    
public function __construct(Mailer $mailer, Request $request)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    $this->request = $request;
}
public function handle(CustomerContactedBullard $event)
{
....   
$this->mailer->send('public.emails.contact_us',$this->request->all(),$params);
}
```

ContactUsController

```
event(new ContactedUs\CustomerContactedUs());
```

Terminal I run

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should add valid entry in EventServiceProvider like so:

```
protected $listen = [
   \App\Events\ContactUs\CustomerContactUs:class => [
      \App\Listeners\ContactedUs\SendCustomerEmailToUs::class,
   ],
];
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I have those classes added to EventServiceProvider. I found my issue. I was using request->get in my listeners. I have to pass form data through the event constructor. The problem Im having now is that my queue is not able to access global scopes of my model. When I query model I have a global scope set. Queue does not access that so I can't query without using withoutGlobalScopes() in my query